# sklearn LinearRegression handles rank deficient matrix

Tags: regression, scikit-learn

I have defined two numpy arrays `X` and `y` as

```
X
(array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  4.],
        [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  1.],
        [ 3.,  3.,  3.,  7.],
        [-1., -1., -1.,  2.],
        [-2., -2., -2., 13.],
        [-3., -3., -3.,  7.]])
y
array([[ 7], [ 7], [16], [-1], [ 7], [-2]])
```

I am trying to solve for `y = Xw`.
It's clear that `rank(X) = 2` since we have 2 independent variables.
But how is `sklearn.LinearRegression` able to fit this dataset?

```
# Applying linear regression model (Normal equation)
reg = LinearRegression().fit(X, y)    
print('rank', reg.rank_)
print('score', reg.score(X, y))
print('w', reg.coef_,)
print('bias', reg.intercept_)
```

It gives the perfect solution. If it solves the equation using normal method, shouldn't it throw the exception that $X^T X$ is non invertible?

```
rank 2
score 1.0
w [[1. 1. 1. 1.]]
bias [-2.66453526e-15]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the expected behavior.

I'll use the same symbols from the `scipy` documentation.

From the `sklearn` documentation, we read that `LinearRegression` is just a wrapper for `scipy.linalg.lstsq`. Reading the documentaiton for `scipy.linalg.lstsq`, we find that this function carries out a specific minimization:

> Compute a vector `x` such that the 2-norm `|b - A x|` is minimized.

In other words, even if there are many $x$ that solve the linear system $Ax=b$, the `scipy.linalg.lstsq` function returns an $x$ that minimizes $\| b - Ax\|_2$.

In your case, the matrix $A$ is rank-deficient, and there are many $x$ that minimize $\| b - Ax \|_2$. In this case, LAPACK is used to compute the solution which minimizes both $\| x \|_2$ and $\| b - Ax \|_2$.

These LAPACK functions have an overview here: http://netlib.org/lapack/lug/node27.html

Comment: How does `lstsq` do it then? How does it handle non-invertibility?

Comment: You don't have to invert a matrix to solve a linear system; it just happens that if there is a unique solution to a linear system, then matrix inversion is an obvious approach. Specifically, `scipy.linalg.lstsq` is calling LAPACK routines which have an overview here: https://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node27.html